# Toggling between provided and included for spark binaries in local run mode

Tags: maven, apache-spark, sbt

A common pattern for building spark applications either in `maven` or `sbt` is to mark the spark binaries as `provided`.  This approach reduces the uber jar size substantially and also avoids version mismatches if the binaries were built for say spark 2.0.0 but deployed on 2.0.1.

The downside of this approach is - how do we run the programs in `local` mode?  In that case there is no spark server to provide the binaries for us.

This is not referring to running *tests*: those live in the `test` directory. Instead the intention is to run precisely the same workflow as will happen on a deployment cluster but locally - including sourcing out of the `main` directory and using the same build file. The preferred answer would be one that only differs by an `sbt` or `maven` command line switch.

So for example in `sbt` (notice the ***provided*** which will omit the binaries):

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core"  % Versions.spark % "provided"
```

We want to *include the spark binaries:

```
sbt package <some switch to include the spark binaries>
```

in maven `pom.xml`

```
     <dependency>
         ..
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

We want to *include* the spark binaries somehow:

```
mvn package <some switch to include the spark binaries>
```